# In Design TOC disappearing on update

Tags: adobe-indesign, table-of-contents

My TOC is designed exactly as I told it to, but it is not showing page numbers at all. And after discovering that I had to place the cursor in the table and choose layout to update it, I did that. But the entire page disappears. I read another reply here that said that the TOC has to be in it's own 'story'. Does this mean that the TOC has to be in separate document (of the book)? It is in the middle of my 'front matter' document at the moment - title page,copyright page, and dedication come first. 
Also, if i try to update the TOC styles with changes to styles, it disappears! 
I'd love it if someone can help me get this working!